# Passing jQuery value using Ajax to a page template

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery code:-

```
jQuery('.fancymember').on('click', function() {
    var member = jQuery(this).parent('div').parent('div').find('.test').val();
    var dataString = 'member='+ member;
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://website.dev/wp-content/themes/website/template-about.php",
      data: dataString,
      dataType: 'text',
      success:function(event){
      //    alert(member);
            jQuery('#test2').val(member);
      }
    });

});
```

I want to pass the value 'member' to use in a Wordpress page template, I am trying to retrieve the value as follows:-

```
<?php $testing = $_POST['member']; ?>
```

But when I do:-

```
<?php var_dump($testing); ?>
```

$testing is NULL, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I've tried to pass it to the page name as well but that didn't work (`url: "get-to-know-us",`)

Okay just checked in firebug console and I get the following error:-

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function get_header() in **/Applications/AMPPS/www/distinct.dev
/wp-content/themes/distinct/template-about.php** on line **6**

However, using `url: "get-to-know-us",` I can see it has posted the value:-

member  71
Source member=71

So I still don't understand why I can't display this in PHP?

Comment: If you open your browser's developer tools and trigger the request - you should be able to view the request sent to the ajax script and make sure that the data is being passed along correctly.

Comment: @AricWatson - Updated the question

Comment: you can't load template files directly, WordPress is not loaded in that context.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? I think you need to rethink your approach because from the limited info you've provided it's not making a whole lot of sense why you you want to pass the var back to php

Comment: @JoeyYax, passing a var back to php like this would be helpful in the case of 3rd party site widgets where you need to get information from the site.